# How to prevent auto tag creation in tagging mode in Select2 v3.x?

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I am using select2 version 3.4.5.

I am not sure whether it is possible to disable the automatic creation of arbitrary tags the user types. I only want them to select from existing tags.

Is this possible?

(I'm using Select2 3.x rather than 4 because the tagging mode is nicer to use. In select2 4 it has to use a multiple select element and the tag order is fixed - I want the tags to remain in the order the user typed them in and this is not possible in v4)